# Creating word count columns based off of specified list of words

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column full of sentences. I want to create 3 columns that show the count of times a word was used for that caption within the same original df.

Ex:

With this psudeo data:

```
d = {'post': ['post1', 'post2', 'post3'], 'caption': ['The blue dog went to see the red house.', 'The green frog sat on a green leaf.', 'Hello World!']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    post    caption
0   post1   The blue dog went to see the red house.
1   post2   The green frog sat on a green leaf.
2   post3   Hello World!
```

And these selected words:

```
words = ['green', 'blue', 'red']
```

I would want this result:

```
    post    caption                                    green    blue    red
0   post1   The blue dog went to see the red house.        0    1       1
1   post2   The green frog sat on a green leaf.            2    0       0
2   post3   Hello World!                                   0    0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `findall` and `explode` + `get_dummies`

```
df = df.join(df.caption.str.findall('|'.join(['green','blue','red'])).explode().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0))
df
Out[335]: 
    post                                  caption  blue  green  red
0  post1  The blue dog went to see the red house.     1      0    1
1  post2      The green frog sat on a green leaf.     0      2    0
2  post3                             Hello World!     0      0    0
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it only partially worked. The words I used were ["eco", "eco-friendly", "green", "organic", "clean", "sustainable", "sustainability"] and it only created columns for "eco", "organic", and "sustainable". I am unsure why it did not create all 7 columns??